# Can we use mysql with ethereum?

Tags: mysql, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

We are thinking of building a dapp for finding salon near me and allowing booking. In such application end users has to be shown the salons which are at a certain distance from their current location. Where would be query that data from. Cause I don't think so that kind of querying is possible in solidity. Do we need to bring in any RDBMS in such a scenario to store salon data so that we can query it easily and booking information can be sent to blockchain.

Is hybrid application the only way out? People are talking about IPFS should be used for storing the images, videos and other data. Is that the solution, if yes then how would we query it from there? Moreover, would it  be fast enough?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Short answer: you might, but you shouldn't.

The real question here is what do you need ethereum for in this project?

In Ethereum, each write operation is costly whereas reading data isn't. Write operations are `transactions`, read are `calls`.
It means that "uploading" your salon list will cost you money (i.e. [gas](https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/guides/what-is-the-gas-in-ethereum/)), but also each data update (opening hours, booking ..).

For the mysql specific part of your question, well Ethereum is not designed for that kind of operation.
Something with an oracle might do the trick but it's truly not designed for. See Ethereum like a way to intermediate transactions between peers that stores every transaction publicly and permanently.
According to the Wikipedia page [blockchains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain) are basically a "continuously growing list of records". Ethereum has the possibility to make workers run some code in exchange of `gas`.
This code (or [Smart Contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_contract)) only purpose "to facilitate, verify, or enforce the negotiation or performance of a contract" (here contract is a legally binding contract).

---

From what you described, IMO a simple web application with "standard" SQL is more than enough.
You just have to store the salons' GPS coordinates and do the closest match(es) from the user's GPS coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to separate your application into two parts:
 - The part which shows the available booking times
 - The part which makes a new booking

Comment: Where would we store the available booking times? In RDBMS?

Comment: Are the available booking times systematic?  If you have an availability window, with actual bookings removing blocks from that window, then the available times are an exercise in calculation, but if the available times vary in a non-systematic way you would need to have them stored somewhere, and an RDBMS is often a good solution (or a DBMS).

Comment: Does that really matters? My main concern is that can we store that information in  blockchain and retrieve it when user searches per his location?